# if i manually change hash the hash change eventlistner is not triggered

Tags: javascript, html

please i need help with my code.
if i manually change hash the hash change eventlistner is not triggered

```js
//i selected a button from my html
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
//i added an EventListener to change the  hash on click
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  history.pushState("", "", `#${model.state.hash}`);
});

// i added EventListener to tell me if the hash was changed
// but if i click the button the hashchange/ popstate event is not trigged

window.addEventListener("popstate", function () {
  console.log("hash was changed");
});
```

```html
<button class="btn">btn</button>
```

**strong text**

Comment: Certain events only fire on actual user interaction. This prevents undesired "loops" in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...addEventListener("popstate"...` only fires upon actual navigation, not simply a `pushstate()` execution.

So, navigate to your hash target to trigger the `popstate` event:

```
document.location = `#${model.state.hash}`;
```

```js
let model = {state: {hash: "test"}};

//i selected a button from my html
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
//i added an EventListener to change the  hash on click
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.location = `#${model.state.hash}`; // <-- navigate to trigger popstate

  // no need to pushState, since document.location does that
  //history.pushState("", "", `#${model.state.hash}`);
});

// i added EventListener to tell me if the hash was changed
// but if i click the button the hashchange/ popstate event is not trigged

window.addEventListener("popstate", function () {
  console.log("hash was changed");
});
```

```html
<button class="btn">btn</button>
```

Here's a helpful explanation: [JavaScript Popstate Event](https://www.codeguage.com/courses/js/events-popstate-event)

Comment: okayyyy meaning : document.location = `#${model.state.hash}`; will take it to the url. wow it worked love you man ❤❤❤

Comment: Yes, takes the page to the hash location, without a page reload. And that automatically pushes the hash location to the history. If that solves your problem, accept my answer to let others know it helped. :)